# Change property of immutable struct

Tags: swift, struct

I am using a struct which has property `let name: String`

```
struct StudentStruct {
    let name:String
}
```

I am using this in viewDidLoad as

```
  var obj = StudentStruct(name: "Leo")
  var copyObject = obj// Should copy all variables from obj
  obj.name = "Jhon" // Assign new name ... <Giving error>
```

We know that `obj.name = "Jhon"` is not possible due to name is `let` property,

I don't want to alter anything from `StudentStruct`
What is best way to use `StudentStruct` where `name` modification is allowed

Comment: You must create a new object with all property from the old one except name = ”new value" : obj = obj(name: "new value", otherProperty: obj. OtherPtoperty,…)

Comment: @PtitXav Please provide answer in answer section with details

Comment: @loremipsum as question states I DON'T want to alter anything from `StudentStruct`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a pretty common pattern to make a method which returns a similar-but-modified copy of the original instance:

```swift
extension StudentStruct {
    func with(
        name: String = self.name/*,
        otherProp: OtherProp = self.otherProp, etc… */
    ) -> StudentStruct {
        StudentStruct.new(name: name/*, otherProp: otherProp, etc…*/)
    }
}

let leo = StudentStruct(name: "Leo")
let john = leo.with(name: "John")
```

Comment: You are **HERO**

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is wrap the immutable student struct and overshadow the immutable name with a mutable name, like this:

```
struct StudentStruct {
    let name: String
}

struct StudentStructWrapper {
    private var wrapperName: String?
    var name: String {
        get { wrapperName ?? studentStruct.name }
        set { wrapperName = newValue}
    }
    private let studentStruct: StudentStruct
    init(studentStruct: StudentStruct) {
        self.studentStruct = studentStruct
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let student = StudentStruct(name: "Matt")
var wrapper = StudentStructWrapper(studentStruct: student)
print(wrapper.name) // Matt
wrapper.name = "Ethan"
print(wrapper.name) // Ethan
```

By writing similar computed variables for any other properties, you can make the wrapper look effectively just like a StudentStruct except that its name is mutable. Meanwhile the underlying StudentStruct is (obviously) unaffected.

Comment: Good suggestion, but I would start the answer with: "The simplest thing to do is to change `StudentStruct` to have a mutable `name` property. If you don't own `StudentStruct` or there are other considerations where you want to keep the `name` property immutable then..."

Comment: @DuncanC (1) That's already been suggested. (2) The question says "I  don't want to alter anything from StudentStruct". That is a presupposition _of the question_. My answer addresses the question that was actually asked as I actually understood it. I've been in that kind of situation and this is the sort of solution I used. Sure, I could be wrong about what the question is (it wasn't very clearly asked) but that's how I took it. If you think differently, feel free to give your own answer; please don't tell me what to say. Thanks.

Comment: Matt, I did miss the bit about not wanting to change the StudentStruct.